# How many natural weapon attacks would I get?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, natural-weapon

If a character has 3 natural weapons (2 claws and a tail), and has the feats Improved Multiattack (eliminates penalty to attack rolls for secondary attacks, but still uses 1/2 Strength damage bonus) and Improved Rapidstrike (can make up to 4 additional attacks with natural weapon pairs with a cumulative -5 penalty each), how many total attacks would he potentially be able to pull off in a single full-round action?

Comment: Where is the Improved Rapidstrike feat found?

Comment: @EdwardGoodson Rapidstrike and its improved version are in the Draconomicon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Five: Three with one Claw, once with the other, once with the Tail

Improved Rapidstrike means that you get two extra attacks with one of your claws, and you still get your other claw attack and the tail attack (which are not affected by Rapidstrike), up to a maximum of five attacks.

Your attack routine, assuming +15 BAB (minimum for Imp. Rapidstrike) and 1d6 damage on each natural weapon, would be as follows:

> +15/+11/+6 Claw (1d6+Str), +15 Claw (1d6+Str), +15 Tail (1d6+½Str)

The extra attacks granted by Improved Rapidstrike are not secondary attacks so they are not affected by Improved Multiattack. A pair of natural weapons can both be primary, so the second Claw attack isn’t affected either. Imp. Multiattack *does* affect the Tail attack, which is secondary; without it it would be at −5 or −2 with Multiattack.

Personally, without more secondary attacks, I wouldn’t spend the feats on Multiattack and Improved Multiattack. Even with a few more secondaries, I usually find Multiattack to be enough.

Comment: I think you might be misreading Imp. Rapidstrike: "you can make two or more attacks with **one** of those weapons."  The intent is a bit unclear, but seems to be that you make 4 additional attacks with a cumulative -5 penalty on each (though the cumulative part is only explicitly mentioned in the table?)

Comment: Well, it does consistently mention a need for "at least one pair of natural weapons", so maybe it refers to only getting extra attacks from one pair?

Comment: @starwed Huh, you seem to be right. Wow, this is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @Cobalt The prerequisite has nothing to do with the effects. It is merely a prerequisite, the same way Cleave requires Power Attack. You don't only cleave while using Power Attack.

Comment: I still think 4 attacks by way of alternating between the pair would make sense, since they're theoretically the same damage and doing 1-2-1-2 slash combos makes more sense than 1-2-1-1-1, for example.

Comment: @Cobalt The rules pretty frequently don't make much sense. This is a relatively tame example.

Comment: +1 especially on the part about improved multiattack. I recently made an advanced kraken and gave it improved multiattack once it's HD soared high enough. Then I re-examined it and went "hey wait a second..."

Answer (score -1):

He vould be able to make a grand total of 7 attacks. Five of those would be iterative attacks from his main weapon, with the usual cumulative penalties, while two would be his other two natural attacks, at his highest attack bonus due to Improved Multiattack.

This is without factoring in bonus attacks from haste or similar effects.

Comment: Improved Rapidstrike doesn't place a restriction based on BAB.  You can always get 4 extra attacks with it.

Comment: Wow, it's an uber feat (but I see, requires 15 BAB to start with). I'm fixing it right now.

Comment: I'm unsure after re-reading the feat. Is the 5 maximum attacks related to the first claw or to all you natural weapons? Any official reading?

Comment: I think it only applies to a paired set of natural weapons, i.e. claws, but you only get the bonuses for the pair and not the individual claws, like you're alternating between them with each successive hit.

Comment: Well that's exactly what it does not do. It either gives 2 to 4 extra attacks with one of your two same-name natural attacks (but then who would choose 2?) or it gives two extra attacks with one of your two same-mane natural attacks but limits the total natural attacks to no more than four. In any case it's crystal clear that the extra attacks must be done with the same weapon. (Which is why I want to give this a try instead of following Kryan's answer)

Comment: I'm not sure you got what I meant; for paired weapons, each part of the pair usually deals the same amount of damage, so though you're rolling attacks for one of them, so though you are rolling up to four extra attacks for one of them, in-universe you may be alternating between hands with each successive attack as opposed to just flailing about with one of them. It doesn't change the total number of extra attacks you get, just the mental image the feat's result evokes.

Comment: Oh, as a fluff thing only. Because +20/+20/+15/+10/+5/+0 is different from +20/+20/+15/+15/+10/+10